# From independent increments with $0\leq t_1 < ... < t_n$ to $0\leq t_1 \leq ... \leq t_n$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

The usual definition of independent increments for a process I've read is:

$\{B(t_{i+1})-B(t_i): 0\leq t_1 < ... < t_n\}$ are independent r.v.

However, how can we, from the previous definition, get

$\{B(t_{i+1})-B(t_i): 0\leq t_1 \leq ... \leq t_n\}$ are independent r.v.  ?

Specifically, how do we prove that $B(s+t)-B(s)$ is indep. of $B(s)-B(0)$?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If e.g. $t_2=t_1$ then $B_{t_2}-B_{t_1}=0$ and constant random variables are independent wrt to *any* random variable (defined on the same probability space).

Comment: @drhab Thanks for the comment. I've added some more info on what exactly I find it strange...

Comment: Take $t_1=0$, $t_2=s$ and $t_3=s+t$. If $s,t\geq0$ then $0\leq t_1\leq t_2\leq t_3$

Comment: @drhab Ups... Of course!! =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume $t_i = t_{i+1}$ then $$B(t_{i+1}) - B(t_i) = 0$$ and a constant is independent of any random variable.

So actually there are no more information given if we assume "$\le$" instead of "$<$"

Comment: Gono, thanks for the answer. I've added more info on my question to specify what exactly I want to know. Sorry. ;)

Comment: There is no proof needed… it's by definition! 
Take for $s,t > 0$ $$t_1 = 0 < t_2 = s < t_3 = t+s$$ then $$B(t_3) - B(t_2) = B(t+s) - B(s)$$ and $$B(t_2) - B(t_1) = B(s) - B(0)$$ are independent by definition…

Comment: gono, of course! =D